# Unit test BasicAuth using Springboot

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I've implemented `BasicAuth` in my `SpringBoot` application to authenticate few URLs. Somewhat like:

**Configuration class**

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Value("${auth.authenticated}")
        private String[] allAuthenticated;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(allAuthenticated).authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }

@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 1
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
// .... Rest of the code 

    }
```

**application.yml**

```
auth.authenticated: /onlineshop/v1/ecart,/onlineshop/v1/wishlist
```

It is working fine, but I want to unit test this.

I was thinking of a simple test case where I can direclty make an HTTP request to either `/onlineshop/v1/ecart` OR `/onlineshop/v1/wishlist` and somehow check if they are authenticated or not.

I came across this [MockMVC section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#testing-http-basic-authentication), and coded below class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=WebSecurityConfig.class)
public class BasicAuthTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity()) 1
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAuthenticated() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/onlineshop/v1/ecart").with(httpBasic("user","password"))).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }


}
```

But every time it gives me 404 error. So I'm not sure if I've configured it properly or what?

Also if there is some other better way to test BasicAuth, kindly suggest.

*Thank You*

Comment: I would not call this a unit test.

Comment: @Henry, please suggest

Comment: where have you configured username and password

Comment: @Jaiwo99, I've used `configureGlobal()`. Code updated.